# CXF + Java: How to remove xmlns attribute

Tags: java, web-services, dom, soap, cxf

I am working on an application that has to consume a SOAP web service. I created the stubs from the WSDL of the web service using CXF.

One of the elements of the request looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
 @XmlType(name="FolderDetailsType", namespace="http://newyorklife.com/services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses", propOrder={"any"})
public class FolderDetailsType
  implements Serializable
 {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6026937020915831338L;
  @XmlAnyElement
  protected List<Element> any;

 public FolderDetailsType() {}

  public List<Element> getAny()
  {
   if (this.any == null) {
    this.any = new ArrayList();
  }
   return this.any;
   }
 }
```

In my adapter class, where I am creating the entire request, I am creating the element with name "businessTypeCode" and adding it to the list of elements.

```
FolderDetailsType folderDetails = new FolderDetailsType();
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
            Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
            Element businessTypeCode = document.createElement("BusinessTypeCd");
            businessTypeCode.setAttribute("code", requestMetadata.getBusinessTypeCode());
            folderDetails.getAny().add(businessTypeCode);
```

When the CXF generates the request XML, it looks like below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Body>
        <ns21:InsertBusinessDocumentRequest xmlns="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" xmlns:ns10="http://schemas/framework/exceptionentry" xmlns:ns11="http://schemas/framework/systemexception" xmlns:ns12="http://schemas/cim/claim/deathclaim" xmlns:ns13="http://schemas/cim/financialcontract/contract" xmlns:ns14="http://schemas/cim/common/name" xmlns:ns15="http://schemas/framework/baserequest" xmlns:ns16="http://schemas/framework/severity" xmlns:ns17="http://schemas/framework/systemexceptionlocation" xmlns:ns18="http://schemas/framework/status" xmlns:ns19="http://schemas/framework/businessexception" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas/framework/baseresponse" xmlns:ns20="http://schemas/framework/fatalexception" xmlns:ns21="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/businessdocumentmaintenance" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas/framework/contextsummary" xmlns:ns4="http://schemas/framework/param" xmlns:ns5="http://schemas/framework/servicestatus" xmlns:ns6="http://schemas/framework/messagetype" xmlns:ns7="http://schemas/framework/businessandservicestatus" xmlns:ns8="http://schemas/framework/businessstatus" xmlns:ns9="http://schemas/framework/serviceexception">
            <AsOfDt>2011-01-01-04:00</AsOfDt>
            <ApplicationInfo>
                <ApplicationId>ABC</ApplicationId>
                <ApplicationVersion>1.0</ApplicationVersion>
            </ApplicationInfo>
            <FolderInfo>
                <FolderDetails>
                    <BusinessTypeCd xmlns="" xmlns:ns22="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" code="J40"/>
                </FolderDetails>
                <FolderName>GY67898</FolderName>
                <FolderTypeCd code="ABC"/>
            </FolderInfo>
            <MIMETypeCd code="pdf"/>
        </ns21:InsertBusinessDocumentRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As you can see, unlike the other elements of the XML, the BusinessTypeCd element has two xmlns tags - one empty and one with the namespace:

```
<BusinessTypeCd xmlns="" xmlns:ns22="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" code="J40"/>
```

But I want the element to be generated like other elements, like:

```
<BusinessTypeCd code="J40"/>
```

Can somebody tell me how to remove the xmlns tags from the BusinessTypeCd element. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. Posting it here if somebody lands here searching for an answer. I took a different approach. I let the CXF create the SOAP message and then I used the CXF custom interceptor to make changes to the message elements.

Configuration XML:

```
<!-- CXF Bus Configuration -->

<cxf:bus name="clientBus">
    <cxf:outInterceptors>
        <bean class="com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.CustomMessageInterceptor" />
    </cxf:outInterceptors>
    <cxf:features>
        <cxf:logging/>
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

CustomMessageInterceptor.java

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.AbstractPhaseInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.phase.Phase;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class CustomMessageInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

    public CustomMessageInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
        addBefore(SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor.class.getName());
    }

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public void handleMessage(
            Message message) {

        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);

        CachedStream cs = new CachedStream();
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cs);

        message.getInterceptorChain().doIntercept(message);

        try {
            cs.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(cs);
            CachedOutputStream csnew = (CachedOutputStream) message.getContent(OutputStream.class);

            String currentEnvelopeMessage = IOUtils.toString(csnew.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
            csnew.flush();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(csnew);

            if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                log.debug("Outbound message: " + currentEnvelopeMessage);
            }

            String res = changeOutboundMessage(currentEnvelopeMessage);
            if (res != null) {
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    log.debug("Outbound message has been changed: " + res);
                }
            }
            res = res != null ? res : currentEnvelopeMessage;

            InputStream replaceInStream = IOUtils.toInputStream(res, "UTF-8");

            IOUtils.copy(replaceInStream, os);
            replaceInStream.close();
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(replaceInStream);

            os.flush();
            message.setContent(OutputStream.class, os);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(os);

        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Unable to perform change.", ioe);
            throw new RuntimeException(ioe);
        }
    }

    protected String changeOutboundMessage(
            String currentEnvelope) {
        currentEnvelope = currentEnvelope.replace("<ClruInsert xmlns=\"\" xmlns:ns22=\"http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses\">", "<ClruInsert>");
        currentEnvelope = currentEnvelope.replace("<BusinessTypeCd xmlns=\"\" xmlns:ns22=\"http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses\"", "<BusinessTypeCd");

        return currentEnvelope;     
    }

    private class CachedStream extends CachedOutputStream {
        public CachedStream() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

It worked like a charm! :)

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Comment: if you'd like a higher level interface you can modify the Soap DOM, see my response to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494314/howto-modify-a-webservice-request-using-cxf-interceptors-with-org-w3c-dom-node

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Element businessTypeCode = document.createElement("BusinessTypeCd");
```

to

```
Element businessTypeCode = document.createElementNS(
  "http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses", 
  "BusinessTypeCd");
```

and see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#createElementNS-java.lang.String-java.lang.String- for more details.

Comment: @Alochi I tried your solution. And it creates the element as below:                       <BusinessTypeCd:BusinessTypeCd xmlns:BusinessTypeCd="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" xmlns="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" xmlns:BusinessTypeCd="http://services/businessdomain/distributionmanagement/maintenance/maintenancerequestsresponses" code="J40"/> It is not working